# Sinon.js stub and test external function call with object as parameter later modified by ref

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

I'm looking to test the call my function makes to another function, particularly an argument that is an object.

The issue is that sinon.js seems to store a reference to the object parameter given in its arguments array, which is naturally expected.  However, this creates a problem when the parameter is later modified by ref, which changes the *apparent* value of those parameters at the time the function was called.

What's the best way to unit test a situation like this?

Here is a contrived example:

### http://jsfiddle.net/xtfQu/

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);    
    },

    dostuff: function () {
        var coords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.otherstuff(coords);

            coords.x += 10;
        }
    },

    otherstuff: function (coord) {
        // Stubbed
    }
});

test("a test", function() {
    // Arrange
    var blah = new view();

    sinon.stub(blah, 'otherstuff');

    // Act
    blah.dostuff();

    // Assert
    var expectedFirstCallCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    // All assertions on the value of x for a particular call would seem to be impossible.
    // blah.otherstuff.firstCall.args[0].x --> 100
    deepEqual(blah.otherstuff.firstCall.args[0], expectedFirstCallCoords, 'parameter changed by ref, untestable?');
});​
```

I can think of various hacks around this 'issue'.  Is there a cleaner approach that doesn't involve cloning the object or modifying my production code simply for the sake of getting sinon to work?

Comment: This looks like a flaw in Sinon.  It probably should clone the arguments, at least if they are native objects.  Have you asked in their mailing list?  Christian might either have a work-around, or be able to patch it quickly.  Or he might well be able to suggest an alternate technique.  I can't see anything that isn't fairly intrusive.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for the confirmation that I'm not crazy. :)  The only issue with sinon cloning those objects is that tests with strictEquals will fail against them.  If I asserted on instead: `strictEquals(blah.otherstuff.firstCall.args[0], expectedFirstCallCoords)` that would fail against a clone.  In my contrived example, that's no issue but what if `expectedFirstCallCoords` were injected into the function/class?  That'd be very undesired.  Best case, that I can see anyway, is that it'd need to store original object references and cloned objects both, and that would be confusing.

Comment: Yes, I didn't consider strictEquals.  (Do you use that in testing?  I never do.)  I don't really see a great solution for this.  But as to confirming that you're not crazy, I'm going to leave that between you and your shrink!  :-)  Best of luck!

Comment: @ScottSauyet I, personally, consider use of `equal` to be of bad practice.  Consider when you're testing your values that `equal(true, 1);` passes.

Comment: I mostly use JSTestDriver, and the assertion framework's assertEquals is a deep equals compare, but not a reference comparison.  I don't use assertSame, or not often, which is a reference comparison.  But I also have, e.g., assertTrue, assertNotNull, to catch more specific types.  On the other hand, I often **want** any truthy value to pass my boolean tests, so we may have very different standards!  :-)

Comment: As long as you use `equal` with the knowledge that it is indeed truthy that's of course exactly what it's for!  I just like explicitness :).  Also, the thing I was testing in my `equal(true, 1)` was not a boolean, but instead `1`, so expecting an integer and passing a test when I actually got back a boolean (or string) seems wrong to me.  For most boolean cases where I just care about truthy, that's when I use `ok()`.  Net result, now that I think about it, I never use `equal`.  :)  But that's just, I admit, personal preference.  Nice discussion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit to Mantoni on the [related Github discussion](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/184#issuecomment-9473934) on this:

```
var param = { property: 'value' };
var engage = sinon.stub();
var engageWithValue = engage.withArgs(sinon.match({ property : 'value' }));

engage(param);

param.property = 'new value';

sinon.assert.calledOnce(engageWithValue); // passes
```